# Tracking the highest array element

Tags: java, arrays

```
/** (B) declare and create an array to contain at least 100 records */
    String arrayRec[] = new String[100];
/** (B) manually populate a few records ... use supplemental file provided */
    arrayRec[0] = "FirstValue";
    arrayRec[1] = "SecondValue";
    arrayRec[2] = "ThirdValue";
    arrayRec[3] = "FourthValue";
    arrayRec[4] = "FifthValue";
    arrayRec[5] = "SixthValue";
    arrayRec[6] = "SeventhValue";
    arrayRec[7] = "EigthValue";
    arrayRec[8] = "NinthValue";
    arrayRec[9] = "TenthValue";
    /** (B) declare and initialize and integer variable, imax to track the highest array element used (9) */
```

Could anyone tell me what the directions mean by initializing a variable int iMax to "track" the highest array element used (9)?
I dont quite understand it

Comment: You might need to describe where the question came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the "highest" or last element in the array is "TenthValue".

i.e. you have an array of ten strings ( 0 is counted as 1 in arrays ) so the iMax variable keeps a record of the last element in the array as indexes are added to it.

For more information on array have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

*** (B) declare and create an array to contain at least 100 records */
This part claims that you are required to have an array that contains at least 100 records, going by your example your array only has an initial capacity of 10*

```
String arrayRec[] = new String[10];
```

should be:

```
String arrayRec[] = new String[100];
```

For future reference an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) would solve this problem much better but i presume this is a homework assignment for a beginner student?

**Latest Update**

Ive just realised what your question was asking.

Basically you are asked to create an array of size 100 but not fill all of it, just a few indexes.

To do this use the following code:

```
//Create the variable which will hold the last element in the array
int iMax = 0;
String arrayRec[] = new String[100];

arrayRec[0] = "FirstValue";
arrayRec[1] = "SecondValue";
arrayRec[2] = "ThirdValue";
arrayRec[3] = "FourthValue";
arrayRec[4] = "FifthValue";
arrayRec[5] = "SixthValue";
arrayRec[6] = "SeventhValue";
arrayRec[7] = "EigthValue";
arrayRec[8] = "NinthValue";
arrayRec[9] = "TenthValue";

//Run through each index in the array to see how many are filled
//All unfilled indexes will be pre filled with null values
for( String s : arrayRec )
{
    if( s != null ) //if the index does not contain null
    {
        iMax++; //Add another one to the counter
    }
}

System.out.println("Highest element in array = " + iMax); //iMax variable will return ten for the ten values
```

Comment: So what would I do to set it to track the highest one? Or is it already set to do that?

Comment: I dont see any sign of an iMax variable in your example but i will update my answer to provide this.

Comment: I had originally set iMax in place of "arrayRec", but I had a hunch that was wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's a pretty basic beginners assignment. Just started the class yesterday, the link you gave me is pretty informative though. Thank you for your time and effort. +1